# Can you write the differential operator at the back of an expression?

Tags: notation, convention

I'm a tutor for a course on optimization at my uni and today (while correcting exercise sheets) a student presented me with something like this:
$$
0 = (ax^* + b)  \frac{\partial}{\partial x}
$$

Where he put the differential operator **behind** the expression that he was supposed to differentiate.

Is this just notation convention? Are you allowed to do this?

I searched the internet for this and couldn't find anything.

Comment: What is $x^{*}$? If it's a constant then it looks like the expression is just missing something.